# How to disable Pycharm strange protective highlighting feature

Tags: pycharm, ide, highlight

What is this type of partial code highlighting called? I am assuming this is a protective feature. And need to know the name of it so that I can research how to turn it off.

[image: tur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *Column Selection Mode* and you can enable/disable it clicking here:

```
Edit > Column Selection Mode
```